# Is there a library for overlaying questions on embedded YouTube videos?

Tags: youtube

In the [AI class course](http://ai-class.com) by Stanford, they use embedded videos for teaching the course.

After each video users are asked to answer a quiz question.

Is there a library one can use for accomplishing this?

I'd like to use this in creating online content for my students as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like they [implemented](http://ai-class.com/media/js1/topic.js) it themselves. So that would probably mean there's no general library, or they would probably have used that.

They did a nice job, by the way.

Comment: Thanks. I'll peruse the code. Might be worth extracting. I don't feel like using Captivate.